# Apply CSS style to new window without using document.write

Tags: javascript, css

I have opened a new window with the code:

```
w = window.open("", "ventana", "status=1,width=350,height=150");
```

And there I created a table with

```
var tresumen = w.document.createElement("table");
```

and so on, and so on...

Everything works fine, but when it comes to apply CSS, I am finding that the new window is not reading the separate css file that I have referenced from the main html. In the CSS I have some lines for `table` like this:

```
table {
        some attributes here;
}
```

The only way I can think about to make the new window read the CSS, is to put a `document.write` inside the javascript of the new window, putting there the html code to reference (again) the css file, but since it's already referenced in the main html, I don't see why that would be a proper way...

What is my mistake here?

How can I make a new window (without its own html!) read the CSS that the main window is using?

Thanks!

Comment: why new window with js? make a "lightbox" (google it) or maybe target blank?

Comment: In this specific work I need to do new window with js for consistency with the rest of the code (which is already written), but I admit that lightbox is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an actual HTML document loaded or generated inside the new window, you're relying on browsers' tag-soup interpretation to make sense of your markup.

That said, you'd have to append a style or link element to that window's DOM which refers to your external stylesheet.

Comment: Well yes, you are right... I will do some tests to add link element to the DOM, and if not, I will change my approach a bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can copy your styles to the new window:

```
var stylesheets = document.querySelectorAll('style, link[rel="stylesheet"]');
stylesheets = Array.prototype.slice.call(stylesheets);
for (var i = 0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
    copyStyle(window, w, stylesheets[i]);
}

function copyStyle(from, to, node) {
    var doc = to.contentDocument;
    var newStyle = doc.createElement(node.tagName);
    if (node.textContent) {
        newStyle.textContent = node.textContent;
    } else if (node.innerText) {
        newStyle.innerText = node.innerText;
    }
    newStyle.type = node.type;
    newStyle.src = node.src;
    newStyle.rel = node.rel;
    doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newStyle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. A bit too complex for the simple thing I wanted to do, but I save your code. It might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ES6 way to do it but IE will hate it:

```
function copyStyles(sourceDoc, targetDoc) {
  Array.from(sourceDoc.styleSheets).forEach(styleSheet => {
    if (styleSheet.cssRules) { // for <style> elements
      const newStyleEl = sourceDoc.createElement('style');

      Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules).forEach(cssRule => {
        // write the text of each rule into the body of the style element
        newStyleEl.appendChild(sourceDoc.createTextNode(cssRule.cssText));
      });

      targetDoc.head.appendChild(newStyleEl);
    } else if (styleSheet.href) { // for <link> elements loading CSS from a URL
      const newLinkEl = sourceDoc.createElement('link');

      newLinkEl.rel = 'stylesheet';
      newLinkEl.href = styleSheet.href;
      targetDoc.head.appendChild(newLinkEl);
    }
  });
}
```

Stolen from: https://hackernoon.com/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202